# How do I make custom textures for overlays?

Tags: texture, overlay

I have a physical object that has a really nice, unique texture and I would like to duplicate that texture digitally for overlays (2D or 3D).  What steps do I need to take to accomplish that?  What things do I need to watch out for or really pay attention to when doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Photoshop CS5 solution:
1. Take a photograph.
2. Edit the picture, making selections and filling them using the "Content-Aware" to make it seamless.
3. Use Filter/Other/Offset and set the offset to whatever is 50% of height and width (ex. +50, +50).
4. Use Clone Tool to take away all seems.
5. Use Offset once again, this time with negative digits, -50, -50 to reset the texture.

Edges should now be seamless and the texture ready to apply. Use bigger images to make patterns less noticeable.